# Is this question acceptable?

Tags: discussion, asking-questions

I want to ask a question about amateur observing but I am little concerned that it could be considered opinion based and closed. Below is my question, please do not try to answer it here but instead provide comments and critiques of the question so that I may improve it.

---

**Title:** How do I prevent or reduce shake when observing with binoculars?

I have some 16 x 50 binoculars that my parents bought me years ago. Recently I have tried to do some basic lunar and planetary observations with them but I am seriously struggling with shaking. This was most noticeable tonight while attempting to observe the ISS.

While I accept that keeping the image of a moving target stable is going to be next to impossible, I would like to know how I could reduce my shaking while observing the moon and other objects.

Is anyone able to provide some simple techniques to reduce shaking?

**Tags:** TBC

---

If anyone could also suggest tags I'd be very grateful.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The policy about "opinion based" questions is mostly intended to prevent questions that garner dozens of different answers with little or no objective standard to judge their relative merit.

This question might get multiple answers, but each answer would be a *suggestion*, not an opinion, and it would be easy enough for people to try the different suggestions and see how well they work. Thus, an objective standard would exist and the best answers would get voted to the top - which is exactly how Stack Exchange is supposed to work.

For tags, I would consider amateur observing and binoculars.

Comment: I would also find that question completely acceptable.

Comment: Thanks guys! The question is now posted here: http://astronomy.stackexchange.com/questions/15063/how-do-i-prevent-or-reduce-shake-when-observing-with-binoculars